# Group data sets by specific column where column names are the first row in each set

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
$data = array (
    'data1' => array (
        0 => 
        array (
            0 => 'ID',
            1 => 'PinCode',
            2 => 'Date',
            ),
        1 => 
        array (
            0 => '101',
            1 => '454075',
            2 => '2012-03-03',
            ),
        2 => 
        array (
            0 => '103',
            1 => '786075',
            2 => '2012-09-05',
            ),
        ),
    'data2' => array (
        0 => 
        array (
            0 => 'Balance',
            1 => 'ID',
            ),
        1 => 
        array (
            0 => '4533',
            1 => '101',
            )
        ),
    'data3' => array (
        0 => 
        array (
            0 => 'Active',
            1 => 'ID',
            ),
        1 => 
        array (
            0 => 'Yes',
            1 => '101',
            ),
        2 => 
        array (
            0 => 'No',
            1 => '103',
            )
        ),
    );
```

In the `$data` array there are three arrays named data1, data2 and data3 respectively.
In each array, the first row is the name of the columns and the remaining rows are the values for those columns (think of it like a table).

In each data1,data2 and data3 the first row contains a column called ID.

I want to group the data from all three arrays based on the matching ID field such that the final output array is like this:

**Desired Output:**

```
$output = 
array (
    'output' => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
            0 => 'ID',
            1 => 'PinCode',
            2 => 'Date',
            3 => 'Balance',
            4 => 'Active',
            ),
        1 => 
        array (
            0 => '101',
            1 => '454075',
            2 => '2012-03-03',
            3 => '4533',
            4 => 'Yes',
            ),
        2 => 
        array (
            0 => '103',
            1 => '786075',
            2 => '2012-09-05',
            3 => 'null',
            4 => 'No',
            ),
        )
    );
```

What I tried(just a attempt to combine data1 and data2) :

```
$d1=$data['data1'];
$d2=$data['data2'];
if(count($d1)>count($d2))
{
    $arr1=array();
    $arr2=array();
    $arr3=array();
    $column1=$d1[0];
    $column2=$d2[0];

    for($i=1;$i<=(count($d1)-1);$i++)
    {
        if($i<count($d2))
            $arr2[]=array_combine($column2,$d2[$i]);
        else
            $arr2[]=array_combine($column2,array('0'=>'','1'=>''));
    }

    for($i=1;$i<=(count($d1)-1);$i++)
    {
        $arr1[]=array_combine($column1,$d1[$i]);
    }
    for($i=0;$i<=(count($arr1)-1);$i++)
    {
        $arr3[]=array_merge($arr1[$i],$arr2[$i]);
    }
    print_r($arr3);
}
```

I need help regarding a neat code to combine any number of arrays.

Notice that missing elements should receive a null value.

How do I get the output I have mentioned above?

Comment: Does your ID is primary key? why don't put it as array key?

Comment: Yes the ID is unique. Can you show me how to get the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This splits it into 2 steps, first accumulate all the data by the ID, also all the header columns are collected.  Then use this data to create output array with blanks where the data is missing.

Comments in code...

```
$store = [];
$headers = [];
foreach ( $data as $set )  {
    $headerRow = array_shift($set);
    // Collect all header columns
    $headers = array_merge($headers, $headerRow);
    foreach ( $set as $index => $list ){
        // Create associative list of data so they can be combined (i.e. ID fields)
        $list = array_combine($headerRow, $list);
        // Use ID value as key and create if needed
        if ( !isset($store[$list["ID"]]) )    {
            $store[$list["ID"]] = $list;
        }
        else    {
            $store[$list["ID"]] = array_merge($store[$list["ID"]], $list);
        }
    }
}

$headers = array_unique($headers);
$output = [ 'output' => [$headers]];
// Create template array, so that missing fields will be set to null
$blank = array_fill_keys($headers, null);
foreach ( $store as $dataRow )  {
    // Fill in the fields for this ID and then change to numeric keys
    $output['output'][] = array_values(array_merge($blank, $dataRow));
}
```

Comment: I have added an "Update" section in my question above with 2 cases. Please help me with those scenarios also. Accepting your answer. Thank you

Comment: It may be worth adding a new question for the second scenario as it is much more complex.  You not only have to work by ID, but remember the order in the ID.  You may find that a different approach is more suitable given this new requirement and others may be able to provide it.  You may also get limited readership of an answered question.

Comment: Don't worry - I'm on SO too much so I will most likely see it.

Comment: hey check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555761/php-merge-arrays-based-on-matching-column-name-with-multiple-entries-or-duplicat)

Comment: sorry for bothering you too much. I have updated the desired output as it would make it easier for me to json_encode it and use it frontend apps. please help me to get that output

Answer (score 1):

Having the keys as the first element of array is not good practice - that why keys are for.

I recommend different approach - use [array-combine](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) for connect them and use the ID as key:

```
foreach($data as $v) {
    $keys = array_shift($v); // take the keys
    foreach($v as &$e) {
        $e = array_combine($keys, $e); // combine the keys and the value

        // add or append them according the ID
        if (!isset($res[$e['ID']])) $res[$e['ID']] = $e;
        else $res[$e['ID']] = array_merge($res[$e['ID']], $e);
    }
}
```

Now you can take this - and if you must convert it back to your structure.

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/rNsXN)

Answer (score 0):

Largely resembling NigelRen's answer, my snippet will group by ID value, apply default null values where appropriate and prepend a row of column names after all other array building is finished.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y7DM0))

```
$result = [];
$uniqueKeys = [];

// group data by ID
foreach ($data as $rows) {
    $keyRow = array_shift($rows);
    $uniqueKeys += array_combine($keyRow, $keyRow);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $assoc = array_combine($keyRow, $row);
        $result[$assoc['ID']] = ($result[$assoc['ID']] ?? []) + $assoc;
    }
}

// apply default null values where missing element and re-index rows
foreach ($result as &$row) {
    $row = array_values(
        array_replace(
            array_fill_keys($uniqueKeys, null),
            $row
        )
    );
}

// prepend row of column names
array_unshift($result, array_values($uniqueKeys));
        
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'ID',
    1 => 'PinCode',
    2 => 'Date',
    3 => 'Balance',
    4 => 'Active',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '101',
    1 => '454075',
    2 => '2012-03-03',
    3 => '4533',
    4 => 'Yes',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '103',
    1 => '786075',
    2 => '2012-09-05',
    3 => NULL,
    4 => 'No',
  ),
)
```